# JQL : show last updated tickets but not by me

Tags: jira, jql

In JIRA I would like to show the last updated tickets (`ORDER BY updated DESC`) that were updated by someone that isn't me (filter).
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There no way to do this with JQL. Only update date is stored.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is using "was" which can be used with status changes or resolution, for example to query something like: status was closed by bob

If you use scriptrunner you also get a similar function for comments: issueFunction in commented("after -4w by jbloggs")

And for work logged: issueFunction in workLogged(on "2015/07/28" by admin)

But probably this would be the closest to what you are looking for:

> lastUpdated (by / inRole / inGroup) Finds issues by the user who last
>   updated them. Example, find all issues that were last updated by
>   members of the Developers role:
>
> issueFunction in lastUpdated('inRole Administrators')

Hope it helps you